# Is there a way to take a battery power source at 7.1volts 15Amps and convert it to 5volts 4Amps?

Tags: voltage, batteries, raspberry-pi, amperage, converter

I'm somewhat new to electrical engineering, I've been messing around with Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to use a 18650 battery pack (2 batteries) to power a Raspberry Pi (and some other things such as a Fan HAT).

I'm trying to convert that 7.1volt 15Amp battery pack to something around 5volt 4Amp. How should I go about doing this? Would it be easier to try and find a battery pack for 5volts 4amps?

Comment: Yes, use a buck converter.

Comment: Is that something I can buy? How would I make that for what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you see a power supply rated at \$V\$ volts and \$A\$ amps, it usually means that it'll produce \$V\$ volts at **up to** \$A\$ amps.  If you present that supply with a device that'll take \$V\$ volts and consume \$A / 3\$ amps -- that's what'll happen.  For any given load presented with any given voltage, it'll take what current it takes.  A source cannot force a voltage **and current** on a load -- only one or the other.

Moreover, when a battery pack is marked \$V\$ volts, it's just understood that the rating is *nominal*.  For batteries, that's usually the voltage at the middle of their useful discharge curve.  So your "7.1V" battery pack will put out 8V or more when it's freshly charged, and as low as 6.4" when it's discharged.  Moreover, Li-anything batteries (Li-Ion, Li-polymer, Li-Fe, etc.) pretty much kill themselves when you discharge them too far, so you need to use a circuit that has a low-voltage cutoff, or you need to lay in a supply of extra cells.  You also need to be careful if through accident you do over-discharge them, because unprotected cells that have been discharged too far can catch fire when you recharge them.

Second, there's an infinite number of ways you can skin this cat, but there's three that I'm going to mention:

1. Obvious, but *don't do this*: use a resistor that drops 2.1V at 4A.  This seems like a good idea, but both the battery voltage and the load current will vary, so you'll get just about anything but 5V at the output.
2. Electrically easy, but thermally hard: use a 5V linear regulator rated for 5A, like a 7805, and a **big** heat sink.  Linear regulators work by passing the load current and dropping voltage through the device, which basically means they burn up a bunch of power as a price of electrical simplicity.  So with an 8V battery your regulator will need to dissipate 12W -- this will require a big heat sink.
3. A bit harder, with pitfalls, but efficient and cool (in the sense that you can touch bits of the circuit and not get burnt): Use a buck converter as @Hearth mentions.  You can buy cheap no-name modules for this off of eBay, you can buy more trusty modules for this from distributors like DigiKey, Mouser, etc., in the US or Farnell in Europe.  The cheap modules tend to just copy the datasheet circuit, and don't always do the job.

You mention a fan -- this can be problematical, because typically a circuit with a motor in it that's rated for a current and voltage will give you the current that the motor will need *once it is spinning*.  There may be some "inrush" current, possibly much higher, needed to actually start the motor.  I say "may" because one *could* design a fan circuit to limit the inrush current -- I just have little faith that it's actually done.

So I recommend that, first, you have a separate buck converter for your "clean" 5V supplies (your Arduino and any other logic) and your "dirty" 5V supplies (your fan module).  Then I recommend that you read the fan module's datasheet carefully for inrush current.  Batteries can easily handle brief overloads (i.e., a battery rated for 4A could do 12A for 1/10th of a second, no problem).  Buck converters can't (unless "brief" means 10 **milli**seconds, and maybe not then).  So your "dirty" 5V supply needs to be sized for the inrush current of any motors & whatnot.

And shop carefully for your module -- I can't tell you who's reliable beyond CUI and TI, and I don't even know if CUI makes modules.  But if you get something cheap from a surplus place, an auction house, or someone that also sells dishware, you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Thanks for the input, The problem I have specifically is I tried using resistors to convert the power to 5volts but it doesn't power up. It works with a DC jack that gives 5v and 4amps so I'm trying to match that. So since just changing it to 5volts did nothing, I noticed the batteries are rated at 15A and the dc jack is rated at 4A. I'm assuming that my issue is my Amps are too high.

Comment: Computers generally need nicely regulated power -- if you look at the Arduino specifications it should say something like "5V \$\pm\$ 0.25V", or "4.75V to 5.25V".  There's no way you can keep the input power to the Arduino within spec without a regulated supply.

Answer (score 0):

7.1V and 15A implies that the power of the battery is 106W. What you are asking is if you can transform that into 20W. That is not a good way of looking at it. Your total power (aside from converter losses when you lower the voltage) will not change. In this case you want to manipulate just voltage, and there are several ways of doing this.

1.) A linear converter that transforms excess voltage into heat, which is not recommended because you have a battery powered application, meaning that every bit of efficiency is important.

2.) Step down (buck) converter. This is your best bet, since good ones have up to 94% efficiency rating. Realistically it will probably be between 80 and 85.

That being said, RPI is a massive power consumer. The lowest you can get RPI zero to go after disabling all kinds of peripherals (HDMI,USB,WiFi etc.) is about 130mA, but by that point it doesn't do much that would justify using RPI. Check the capacity of your battery and calculate for how long you will be able to run your project before it needs to be recharged. Also, since RPI is a computer, roughly cutting power (which is what will happen when the battery runs out) can lead to data/image corruption. Perhaps it is worth considering switching to a microcontroller which would be much less power hungry.